# Definite or indefinite article before the words - dryer and washing machine

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

Let's say that you are reading an article where you find the following sentence.

> Everybody wants to have the possibility of washing in the washing
>   machine and drying in the dryer.

It is ok if I will use the definite article before the words - washing machine and dryer even if I have mentioned them in the article for the first time? I think that everybody has only one washing machine and dryer. Or the indefinite article would be better?

Comment: If you wanted to emphasize that each person is using their own personal washing machine and dryer, then I would use the phrase "their own" instead of the article "the".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to say.

> Everybody wants to have the possibility of washing in **the** washing machine and drying in **the** dryer.

- there's a single washing machine and a single dryer that everybody wants to use

> Everybody wants to have the possibility of washing in **a** washing machine and drying in **a** dryer.

- everybody wants to use any washing machine and any dryer, in general (as opposed to, for example, washing their clothes in a sink and hanging them to dry).

Comment: Exactly right - if you use the definite article, then I picture a situation like a single laundry room in the basement of an apartment building where every person in the building is sharing the same two laundry machines.